# SQL command to sum by day/month

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
+----+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| id | stat_time           |       reads |          writes |
+----+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+
|  1 | 2013-07-18 20:00:00 |    42614543 |         1342129 |
|  2 | 2013-07-18 21:00:00 |    23085319 |          326139 |
|  3 | 2013-07-25 12:00:00 |           0 |           39639 |
|  4 | 2013-07-25 13:00:00 |      754166 |           39639 |
|  5 | 2013-07-25 14:00:00 |      693382 |          295323 |
|  6 | 2013-07-25 15:00:00 |     1334462 |               0 |
|  7 | 2013-07-25 16:00:00 |    10748367 |          261489 |
|  9 | 2013-07-25 17:00:00 |     4337294 |               0 |
| 10 | 2013-07-25 18:00:00 |     3002796 |               0 |
| 11 | 2013-07-25 20:00:00 |     3002832 |               0 |
| 12 | 2013-07-25 23:00:00 |           0 |          333468 |
| 13 | 2013-07-26 17:00:00 |    10009585 |               0 |
| 15 | 2013-07-26 18:00:00 |     6005752 |               0 |
| 17 | 2013-07-26 21:00:00 |      333663 |               0 |
+----+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

I would like to perform something like this:

`SELECT stat_time, SUM(reads), SUM(writes) from this_table GROUP BY stat_time HAVING 'the same day'..`

So a command which outputs three rows (one for 2013-07-18, second one for 2013-07-25 and third one for 2013-07-26) and in every such row in the column reads/writes there is a sum of reads/writes in this day.

Thank you,
David

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want to convert the `stat_time` to a day to do this.  The method depends on the database.  Here is one way:

```
SELECT cast(stat_time as date) as stat_day, SUM(reads), SUM(writes)
from this_table
GROUP BY cast(stat_time as date)
order by stat_day;
```

Here are some other approaches (for MySQL and Oracle):

```
SELECT date(stat_time) as stat_day, SUM(reads), SUM(writes)
from this_table
GROUP BY date(stat_time)
order by stat_day;

SELECT trunc(stat_time) as stat_day, SUM(reads), SUM(writes)
from this_table
GROUP BY trunc(stat_time)
order by stat_day;
```

Comment: It looks perfect! Thank you. This is a query to MySQL, so what is a function which returns 2013-07-26 if I give it the argument 2013-07-26 17:00:00 (the same question for month, so for return value equal to 2013-07). Thanks again.

Comment: @user2042985 . . . The middle query is MySQL syntax.  The function is `date()`.

Answer (score 0):

let's assume you have a column with name D-DATE_START so

```
$query = 'SELECT cast(D_DATE_START as date) as stat_day ,'
        .'sum(I_REV_MODEL) as totalDayRevenu '
        .'FROM t_show WHERE FK_MODEL=136 '
        ."and t_show.D_DATE_START between '".$after."' and '".$before."'"
        .' GROUP BY cast(D_DATE_START as date) '
        .' ORDER BY stat_day ';
```